# EXECUTE AS returning wrong user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm running into a weird situation. This code is running fine on all but one server.

> set nocount on
>   SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();
>   execute as user = 'guest';
>   SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();
>   revert;
>   SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();

This returns my username for the first and third statements on all servers. On the problem servers it returns a fellow dev's logon information instead of guest. Something like DOMAIN\joeblow.

Is there a SQL Server setting I should be setting or some other issue I don't know of? We're running SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Are you executing this against master or some other user database?  Is it the same on all 3 servers?

Comment: The problem is with any database on the database instance, including master. On the other instances/servers, it is working as expected.

Comment: Ok, now it is a little bit more weird. In the example I gave, it is working correctly joeblow.

Comment: Check the server login that the "guest" database user is mapped to.  My guess is that on your trouble server instance, the "guest" user might somehow be mapped to the "DOMAIN\joeblow" server login.  `SELECT UserName = dp.name, Usertype = dp.type_desc, ServerLoginName = sp.name, ServerLoginType = sp.type_desc FROM sys.database_principals dp left join sys.server_principals sp on dp.sid = sp.sid WHERE dp.name like 'guest'`

Comment: Or you can open SQL Server Mgt Studio, and under Databases > YourDatabaseName > Security > Users, right-click on the "guest" database user, select "properties", and look at the "login name" value to see if it is 'DOMAIN\joeblow'.

Comment: Thanks for your help. User name is simply 'guest' however. I see nothing linking that user with our 'joeblow'.